# Why can't generic structs have static members which specify the generic type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, struct, typeloadexception

Apologies if this is a duplicate! I searched around but wasn't able to find an explanation. The following toy example gives me a TypeLoadException as soon as I try to instantiate this struct. It works just fine if I use a class or if instead do not specify the generic type in the static member (leave it as T.)

```
public struct Point<T>
{
    static Point<int> IntOrigin = new Point<int>(0, 0);

    T X { get; }
    T Y { get; }

    public Point(T x, T y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

My rather more complicated, real situation boils down to something like this, so I'd really like to understand why it emits a TypeLoadException.

Comment: Weird. I can reproduce your error with Mono and .NET Core. However, with the ".NET Framework" option on dotnetfiddle.net, it gives the compiler error [CS0523](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0523).

Comment: *The following  example gives me a TypeLoadException ... It works just fine if I ... do not specify the generic type in the static member* - I didn't understand; the toy example given *doesn't* use T in the static member - so does it give an exception or not? Can you check your question is accurate? It seems to contradict itself

Comment: Can you share the code which throws the exception?

Comment: I found multiple issues [1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/5479), [2](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6924) related to this. Seems like a CLR bug.

Comment: @Sweeper: those Github issues do look related, but not exactly the same scenarios. That said, [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6924#issuecomment-547078135) makes clear that the behavior is long-known. It's curious that dotnetfiddle.net emits the compiler error; I don't have an older version of VS to test with, but I'd guess that five years ago (based on the date of the CS0523 doc page), you'd get a compile-time error instead of runtime. Maybe someone decided that it wasn't technically a code error so the compiler shouldn't prohibit it (i.e. changed in Roslyn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6924#issuecomment-547078135), and [another comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11179#issuecomment-430148594), on Github come closest to addressing the current state of affairs, pointing out why the sort of self-referential struct definition hasn't been allowed, and likely won't be for the foreseeable future.

Even the static member needs the type to be initialized before it can be included in the type layout, but the type initialization needs that static member to be initialized. This cycle of initialization dependencies creates the Catch-22 that results in the runtime exception.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6924#issuecomment-583824203), .NET Core works fine with this pattern. But I found the same failure when I tried your example in a .NET Core project. So either that comment is in error, or there's some subtle difference between the instance-member scenario and your static-member scenario (I didn't bother to investigate any further than that).

It is interesting that the compiler used on dotNETFiddle.net emits a compile-time error, [*"Struct member 'struct2 field' of type 'struct1' causes a cycle in the struct layout"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0523). I don't know why the Visual Studio compiler no longer seems to produce this error (checked in 2017 and 2019). It *seems* like another bug to me. But the discussion on Github around this issue seems to accept that the code is technically valid (i.e. according to the C# specification), so probably there was at some point a conscious decision to remove the compiler error, and let the CLR do the complaining at runtime.

Note that the advice in the error's reference page suggests changing to a `class` instead of a `struct`. Of course, this is often not feasible where a `struct` is being used; it may be important to have a value type. However, in your specific example, there's actually a simple work-around based on that idea. Since your field isn't part of the actual layout of an *instance* of the `struct`, you can move it to a static class used specifically for such values. E.g.:

```cs
public struct Point<T>
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        static Point<int> IntOrigin = new Point<int>(0, 0);
    }

    T X { get; }
    T Y { get; }

    public Point(T x, T y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

Then instead of (for example) `Point<double>.IntOrigin`, you'll need to use `Point<double>.Constants.IntOrigin`. Since the type initialization for each type can be done independently, the cycle in the initialization does not occur and the code runs fine.